# Array() applied to hashes?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Recently I stumbled upon "[The Elements of Style in Ruby #3: Make Sure Something Is an Array](http://batsov.com/articles/2013/06/28/the-elements-of-style-in-ruby-number-3-make-sure-something-is-an-array/)".

TL;DR: The Method `Array()` in Ruby converts anything you put in, into an array and tries to guess what the correct outcome should be:

```
Array(1)     # => [1]
Array([1,2]) # => [1,2]
Array(nil)   # => []
```

So what does `Array({a: :b})` return? I would assume it returns an array with the hash as a value: `[{a: :b}]`.

However, the hash is converted directly into an array: `[:a, :b]`.

I don't just want to put a hash into an array (`[{a: :b}]`). I'd like to have functionality that returns an array no matter what I put in. `Array()` already does that, but it converts a hash to an array in a way that I don't expect.

So, basically the functionality should look like this:

```
NewFancyArrayMethod({a: :b}) # => [{a: :b}]
NewFancyArrayMethod([{a: :b}, {c: :d}]) # => [{a: :b}, {c: :d}]
```

The second part is already fulfilled by `Array()`.

I know I can do something like `values = [values] unless values.is_a? Array`, like the article points out. However, I would rather have a method that abstracts this conversion from me as `Array()` already does. The only problem is that `Array()` treats a hash differently than any other "single" value (String, Integer, Object, etc.). I simply don't want different handling for different cases.

Comment: You mean besides just putting array brackets around it?

Comment: I can do that, when I have a single hash. But when I have a list of hashes I'd like to get the same result.

Comment: @leifg could you give an example of the input and desired output?

Comment: If you have a "list of hashes", don't you *already* have an array?

Comment: Do you, or do you not, want to put a hash into an array as `[{a: :b}]`? Your description says both, and is contradictory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Frederick Cheung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064226/frederick-cheung) pointed out in a commend, the method [Array#wrap](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/wrap/class) does exactly what I desire:

```
Array.wrap({a: :b})
# => [{a: :b}]
```

Unfortunately this method is only part of ActiveSupport, so it can't be used in plain Ruby projects.

Comment: Note: `Array.wrap` is from `active_support` which is a part of Rails, but you can just copy the source if you're not using Rails, it's a pretty simple method (just click the "Show source" link in the link in the answer above).

Answer (score 8):

> So what does `Array({a: :b})` return? I would assume it returns an array with the hash as a value: `[{a: :b}]`.

Your assumption is wrong. [`Kernel#Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) converts the argument `arg` by trying (in that order):

1. `arg.to_ary`
2. `arg.to_a`
3. and finally creates `[arg]`

**Examples:**

```
Array(1)        #=> [1]
```

This is because of (3). There's no `Fixnum#to_ary` or `Fixnum#to_a`

```
Array([1, 2])   #=> [1, 2]
```

This doesn't return `[[1, 2]]` because of (1). [`Array#to_ary`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-to_ary) returns `self`

```
Array(nil)      #=> []
```

This doesn't return `[nil]` because of (2). There's no `NilClass#to_ary` but there's [`NilClass#to_a`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/NilClass.html#method-i-to_a): *"Always returns an empty array."*

```
Array({a: :b})  #=> [[:a, :b]]
```

Like `Array(nil)` this doesn't return `[{a: :b}]` because of (2). There's no `Hash#to_ary` but there's [`Hash#to_a`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-to_a): *"Converts hsh to a nested array of [ key, value ] arrays."*

```
Array(Time.now) #=> [33, 42, 17, 22, 8, 2013, 4, 234, true, "CEST"]
```

This is [`Time#to_a`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#method-i-to_a) returning ... *"a ten-element array of values for time"*

**Conclusion:**

`Kernel#Array` works as expected, `Hash#to_a` is the culprit. (or `to_a` in general)

> I'd like to have a functionality, that returns an array no matter what I put in.

`Hash` and `Array` are different objects. You could check the type (`Kernel#Array` does this, too):

```
def hash_to_array(h)
  h.is_a?(Array) ? h : [h]
end
```

Or extend `Hash` (or even `Object`) and `Array`:

```
class Hash # or Object
  def my_to_a
    [self]
  end
end

class Array
  def my_to_a
    self
  end
end
```

See the comments for alternative implementations.

Comment: To handle all objects, you would monkey patch `Object`: `class Object; def my_to_a; [self] end end`

Comment: In that case I would do: `class Object; def my_to_a; [self].flatten end end`  That way you don't have to extend `Object` *and* `Array` ;-)

Comment: @Mischa good point! `is_a?(Array) ? self : [self]` would work, too.

Comment: You could also replace Array() with something like Array.wrap from activesupport (which is similar to Array() but tries only to_ary, not to_a). using flatten changes the behaviour for cases like Array([[1]])

Comment: @FrederickCheung that's exactly what the OP is looking for *"Wraps its argument in an array unless it is already an array"*

Comment: Exactly, so Array([[1]]).should == [[1]], but with [self].flatten you'd get [1]

Comment: The best answers don't just solve the problem, but educate as well.  Nicely done.

Answer (score 1):

Then do monkey patch as below:

```
class Hash
  def fancyarraymethod
    [self]
  end
end
class Array
  def fancyarraymethod
    self
  end
end

{a: :b}.fancyarraymethod # => [{a: :b}]
[{a: :b}, {c: :d}].fancyarraymethod # => [{a: :b}, {c: :d}]
```

Comment: I totally overlooked your answer :)

Comment: @Stefan Its OK... But your `Kernal#Array` explanation(point wise),I liked heavily..At least you saved my time for my self study on that concept..that's why I am happy to give you *+1*...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know wether it's an array or a hash you're working with you can use [`flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) to prevent ending up with a nested array in case of the latter. Like this:

```
[foo].flatten

# E.g.
foo = [{:a => :b}, {:c => :d}]
[foo] #=> [[{:a => :b}, {:c => :d}]] -- Nested, call flatten to fix that
[foo].flatten #=> [{:a => :b}, {:c => :d}]

foo = {:a => :b}
[foo] #=> [{:a => :b}] -- Not nested, call flatten anyway just in case
[foo].flatten #=> [{:a => :b}]
```

This also works for strings, integers and objects:

```
foo = 'bar'
[foo].flatten #=> ['bar']

foo = 1
[foo].flatten #=> [1]

foo = Object.new
[foo].flatten #=> [#<Object:0x00000100a8daf8>]
```

In any case you get what you want.

Comment: `array = [list_of_hashes]` would return a nested array.

Comment: Of course, but I think the OP looks for a methods that handles both cases.

Comment: Maybe that should be `flatten(1)` to preserve deeply nested arrays